# Validation of name flied

Tags: javascript

```html
<html>

<body>
  <form method="POST" action="" />
  </br>
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" required onkeypress="javascript:return checkNum(event)" />
  </br>
  </br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
</body>
<script>
  function checkNum() {

    if ((event.keyCode > 64) || (event.keyCode > 96 && event.keyCode < 123) || event.keyCode == 8)
      return true;
    else {
      alert("Please enter only char");
      return false;
    }

  }
</script>
```

This code validates the name field by restricting special characters and space. But  i need to enter a space between the fullname.

Comment: What are you trying to ask?

Comment: Textbox restricts the entry values of special characters and spacebar.But i need to accept space between the firstname and secondname.

Comment: [`keyCode` is deprecated.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)

Comment: The code for a space is keyCode==32. That should give you a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add the keycode for a space (which is `32` found [here](http://keycode.info/)) to the `if()` like seen in the snippet. This will stop the function from blocking the entry of a space in the input

To put it between the first and last name you'll have to add a check for the length of the input field before allowing the addition of a `space`

```html
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST" action=""/>
</br>
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" required onkeypress="javascript:return checkNum(event)"/>
</br></br>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
<script>
function checkNum()
{

if ((event.keyCode > 64 ) || (event.keyCode > 96 && event.keyCode < 123) || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 32)
//Added event.keyCode == 32 to the conditionals
   return true;
else
   {
       alert("Please enter only char");
       return false;
   }

}
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I Included the char code to allow for space which is 32 as well as backspace, delete and your own a-z, A-Z, 1-9 etc...

```
checknum(event)
    {           
        var val = event.charCode;
       return((val > 64 && val < 91) || (val > 96 && val < 123) || val == 8 || val == 32 || (val >= 48 && val <= 57)); 
    }
```

Comment: Please add a description of what you did as it may help the questioner.